# OpenGL driver for radeon Curacao PRO R7 370 / R9 270/370

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, opengl, amd-graphics

I have an AMD/ATI Curacao PRO R7 370 / R9 270/370 graphics card in a Dell T7400 workstation running lubuntu 14.04 (currently, but would eventually like to upgrade to 16.04).

As far as I can tell, the card should be able to support boinc calculations, but boinc reports no suitable GPU found.

As a newbie to linux, I'm kind of lost here on how to install the appropriate driver for this?

Comment: If you're running 14.04, you can still install the `fglrx` driver